# Compute the exponential of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How we can show that 
$$e^{At}=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\mu}[(\mu\cos\mu t+\lambda\sin\mu t)I +A\sin(\mu t)]$$ 
where 
$$\lambda=\frac{a_0}{2},\qquad 
\mu=\left(\omega^{2}-\frac{a^{2}_{0}}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
and 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
   -\omega^{2} & -a_{0} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Show that the right hand side satisfies the differential equation with the same initial conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tedious, but straightforward. The key to simplifying here is to note that $A^2$ can be written in terms of $I,A$ (Cayley Hamilton).

Let $f(t) = \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\mu}((\mu\cos(\mu t)+\lambda\sin(\mu t))I +\sin(\mu t)A )$. Then $f(0) = I$. Furthermore,
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(t) &=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\mu}\left( -\lambda(\mu\cos(\mu t)+\lambda\sin(\mu t)I +\sin(\mu t) A ) + (-\mu^2\sin(\mu t)+\lambda\mu\cos(\mu t))I +\mu \cos(\mu t) A \right) \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\mu}\left( -\lambda(\lambda\sin(\mu t)I +\sin(\mu t) A ) + (-\mu^2\sin(\mu t))I +\mu \cos(\mu t) A \right) \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\mu}\left( -(\lambda^2+\mu^2)\sin(\mu t)I + (\mu \cos(\mu t) -\lambda \sin (\mu t)) A \right)
\end{eqnarray}

Note that $A= -{1 \over 2 \lambda} (A^2+\omega^2 I)$ and so $A^2 = -(\omega^2 I+2 \lambda A)$.
Also note that $\mu^2+\lambda^2 = \omega^2$.
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
Af(t) &=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\mu}((\mu\cos(\mu t)+\lambda\sin(\mu t))A +\sin(\mu t)A^2 ) \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\mu}((\mu\cos(\mu t)+\lambda\sin(\mu t))A -\sin(\mu t)( (\mu^2+\lambda^2)I +2 \lambda A) \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\mu}\left( -(\lambda^2+\mu^2)\sin(\mu t)I + (\mu \cos(\mu t) -\lambda \sin (\mu t)) A \right)
\end{eqnarray}
Consequently $f'(t) = A f(t)$.

The equation $x' = A x$ satisfies a global Lipschitz condition hence a solution exists and is unique.

Since $t \mapsto e^{At}$ satisfies this equation with the same initial condition, we see that $f(t) = e^{At}$ for all $t$.